# Ошибка при отправке письма SMTP WP Openserver

Tags: wordpress, email, плагин, wp-plugin

Добрый день вечер, у меня вылетает ошибка при отправке тестового письма из плагина `wp_mail_smtp` не пойму в чем проблема. Может кто подскажет. И сразу вопрос, должны ли быть одинаковые настройки на OpenServer и в настройках плагина?

Вот что выводит при отправке тестового письма. И данные которые я вводил.

> SERVER: QUIT 2017-10-17 14:29:08  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
>   2017-10-17 14:29:08   SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 2.0.0 closing
>   connection q63sm2037701lfd.34 - gsmtp " 2017-10-17 14:29:08 SERVER ->
>   CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection q63sm2037701lfd.34 - gsmtp
>   2017-10-17 14:29:08   Connection: closed

[image: first][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так же выдает такую ошибку  string(640) "The following From address failed: testworks.test.1@gmail.com : MAIL FROM command failed,Authentication Required. Learn more at
 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError w88sm2091024lfd.1 - gsmtp

Answer (score 0):

Вам Gmail ясно пишет: отправка с  адреса testworks.test.1@gmail.com не удалась. Нужна аутентификация.

Выберите Yes: Use SMTP authentication.

Comment: Все равно пишет что нет аутентификации. Может подскажете что еще глянуть?

Comment: Адрес Gmail такой существует?)

Comment: Да, конечно существует )